# DataRange and ScalingFunctions with Log in ListDensityPlot

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

I want to use ListDensityPlot and ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", None}] to show "data" results.
The demension of data is 34*200.

```
In[1]:= data // Dimensions

Out[1]= {34, 200}
```

If i use

```
 ListDensityPlot[data, PlotRange -> All, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", None}]]
```

to generate the figure, everything is ok. As shown below,

[image: the result without Datarange]

But when I try to set the Datarange of "X" from 0.1 to 20, "Y" is from 1 to 34, the final result will be "different", as shown below.

```
ListDensityPlot[data, PlotRange -> All, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", None}, DataRange -> {{0.1, 20}, {1, 34}}]
```

[image: the result with Datarange]

Why does it lead to such results? Is this a bug? How can I configure it to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Version
```

> "13.1.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)"

This issue has been noted as a bug in several previous posts:

#### [Search results - scalingfunctions datarange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=scalingfunctions+datarange)

[image]

An example that replicates the issue in OP:

```
data = Table[Max[x, y], {x, 1, 10, .1}, {y, 0, 10, .1}];

ldp1 = ListDensityPlot[data, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", None}, 
   ImageSize -> 400];
ldp2 = ListDensityPlot[data, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", None}, 
   ImageSize -> 400, DataRange -> {{0, 5}, {1, 100}}];
Row[{ldp1, ldp2}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

**A work-around:** post-process the output generated without the option `DataRange` and modify tick labels in accordance with desired data range values:

```
ClearAll[modifyTickLabels]
modifyTickLabels[oldRange_, newRange_] := ReplaceAll[ _FormBox -> ""]@
    ReplaceAll[FormBox[s_String?(StringMatchQ[NumberString]), ___] :> 
       Rescale[FromDigits[s], oldRange, newRange]]@
     AbsoluteOptions[#, FrameTicks][[1]] &;
```

Use `modifyTickLabels` to construct a custom [`DisplayFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DisplayFunction.html):

```
displayFunction = Show[#, modifyTickLabels[{0, 100}, {0, 5}]@ #] &;
```

Use the option `DisplayFunction -> displayFunction` instead of `DataRange ->...` in `ListDensityPlot`:

```
ListDensityPlot[data, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", None}, 
 ImageSize -> 500, DisplayFunction -> displayFunction]
```

[image]

If we replace `"Log"` with `"Reverse"` above, the first code block gives:

[image]

and, after correction, we get

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I thought the new version of MMA could achieve this function through other settings, instead of constructing custom tick labels.